# \w or \u is not recognised for admin user in macOS

Tags: macos, zsh, user-permissions

I tried to change the prompt in the terminal to use just the current working directory and remove any other text, so I created a file called `.bash_profile` and added this entry  `export PS1='\w $'` sourced it, and now I am only seeing this in the Terminal prompt `\w $` Which was not what I am hoping to see at all!. Interestingly when I sudo login in the terminal, it is actually printing the current working directory like `/Users/<my user> $`.

I also tried the same by creating different files `.profile` or `.bashrc` and nothing seems to work. Please advise.

Comment: You are probably using `zsh`, which uses different prompt escapes.

Comment: Run `echo $0` to check which shell you're using. If you want to change it to Bash run: `chsh -s /bin/bash`

Comment: You guys are right! I am using zsh, and do you know which prompt escapes I should be using?

Comment: @JohnXavier Try `PS1='%/ $'` or `PS1='%d $'`, or maybe you want `PS1='%2C $'` to show only the last two parts of the path. You also probably want to add it to `~/.zprofile` and not  `~/.bash_profile`. See [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) for zsh prompt sequences. AFAIK ansi colors need to be escaped with a dollar, for instance the following colors last two parts of the path light gray: `PS1=$'\e[90m%2C\e[0m $'`

Comment: Thanks @RobC  PS1='%d $' is what I wanted. It is now working fine as expected.

Comment: I added it .bash_profile and sourced the file in .zshrc file

Comment: @Please don't put settings intended for zsh into .bash_profile, or source it from .zprofile. .bash_profile is for *bash* settings, .zprofile is for zsh settings. If you are only using zsh, you should not be doing anything at all with .bash_profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error shown above, it can be concluded that the shell that is being used is ***'zsh'*** and not ***'bash'***

In zsh, the current working directory is represented by '%/'

**How to fix the problem?**

1. Create a file named ***.zshrc*** in the home directory
2. Add the statement ***export PS1='%/ $'*** to ***.zshrc***
3. Open a new terminal to test whether the prompt is showing current working directory.

**Other variations that can be tried**

```
export PS1='%1/ $'
```

will show only the name of the current directory (I.E., the full path is omitted)

```
export PS1='%~/ $'
```

will replace '/Users/username' in the directory path with ~

**A working example:**

```
/Users/macuser1/Desktop/stack-overflow $ pwd
/Users/macuser1/Desktop/stack-overflow   


/Users/macuser1/Desktop/stack-overflow $ export PS1='%/ $'
/Users/macuser1/Desktop/stack-overflow $
/Users/macuser1/Desktop/stack-overflow $


/Users/macuser1/Desktop/stack-overflow $ $export PS1='%~/ $'
~/Desktop/stack-overflow/ $
~/Desktop/stack-overflow/ $


~/Desktop/stack-overflow/ $ export PS1='%1/ $ '
stack-overflow $
stack-overflow $
```